# Sinch - Calls via remote notification do not start

Tags: ios, objective-c, push, sinch

I've set up everything properly for starting calls from a push notification, however the recipient's SINClient does not invoke the client:didReceiveIncomingCall: method, so it's impossible for the user to answer the call.

I've verified my payloads are identical - the results from the relayRemotePushNotificationPayload: method indicate that it's successful and hasn't timed out - this is the same on each and every call.

The delegates do work as I get an invocation from clientDidStart:, I just don't get didReceiveIncomingCall:. I make sure to invoke relayRemotePushNotificationPayload: after connecting to Sinch, as I invoke this in the callback from clientDidStart:, so I'm absolutely certain that the client is connected to Sinch before this payload is passed.

Is there anything else I should be doing to get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you try not waiting until `clientDidStart:` but simply invoke `relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:` directly? The Sinch client will actually automatically start if it's not started as part handling the remote push inside `relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:`.

Comment: how to call method for incoming call in sinch .