# IOS Sinch Calling when Application is offline using APN(Get previously initiated Client )

Tags: ios, sinch

I have successfully integrated Sinch SDK and its working great when the App is open, now i am handling the call when my app is offline.

Using below method i can see the push pairs and i am sending this push pair to server to deliver push .

```
- (void)call:(id<SINCall>)call shouldSendPushNotifications:(NSArray *) pushPairs {

}
```

In Appdelegate.m didFinishLaunchingWithOptions () method, i am getting sinch specific payload .

```
 NSDictionary* remotePush = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    NSLog(@"%@",remotePush);
    if (remotePush) {
        NSLog(@"Entery ****");
        // Extract the Sinch-specific payload from the Apple Remote Push Notification
        NSString* payload = [[remotePush valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"SIN"];

    //    [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"content-available"];
        NSLog(@"Payload :%@",payload);
        // Get previously initiated Sinch client
        id<SINClient> client = _client;
        NSLog(@"Client ID %@",[client userId]);
        id<SINNotificationResult> result = [client relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:payload];
        NSLog(@"Result :%@",result);
        if (result.isCall && result.callResult.isTimedOut) {
            // Present alert notifying about missed call
        } else if (!result.isValid) {
            // Handle error
        }
    }
```

Here is the complete Push notification data:

```
{
        aps =     {
            SIN = "AgEBdeibxmJBSK2Y7Nh/fz50VMhVBVQMKzkxODg0NzE4MjQx";
            alert = "";
            "content-available" = 1;
            type = 2;
        };
    }
```

Coming to this code:

```
// Get previously initiated Sinch client
    id<SINClient> client = _client;
    NSLog(@"Client ID %@",[client userId]);
```

**When i print the client id it is Nil, How i need to get previously initiated Sinch client  ? since App is closed , client instance is released .**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to persist the userId yourself and then when the app is relaunching, initialize a `SinchClient` with the userId you persisted on the last app close.

The simplest is probably using `NSUserDefaults` and saving a field "userId" that you write when the user logs in and remove if the user logs out of your app.

For example, when starting:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:userId forKey:@"userId"];
```

and then when your app is launched via APN:

```
NSString *persistedUserId = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userId"];
if (persistedUserId != nil) {
  _client = [Sinch clientWithApplicationKey:APPLICATION_KEY
                          applicationSecret:APPLICATION_SECRET
                            environmentHost:ENVIRONMENT
                                     userId:persistedUserId];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for swift reply, i have done according to you , now i can see the user id , client is initiated but the call is not relaying . When i print  id<SINNotificationResult> result = [client relayRemotePushNotificationPayload:payload];
        NSLog(@"Result :%@",result);
 Result :<SINNotificationResultImpl: 0x146ee9c0>  . Still Call is not relayed .

Comment: @krish I think that is a separate question, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451427/sinch-calls-via-remote-notification-do-not-start if that might be of assistance